# Pandas dataframe resample difference between methods "BA" and "A"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I found that if I use resample().apply() on a time-indexed dataframe, whose index also happens to end on a year end, using business year end method ("BA") will generate an empty entry for the year after, while using calendar year end ("A") will not. 
I tried to look it up in the documentation but couldn't find anything related to this specific issue.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('20140101', '20191231', freq='B')
a = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
a['A'] = 0.

print(a.resample('A').apply(lambda x: len(x)))
print(a.resample('BA').apply(lambda x: len(x)))
```

The first print yields

```
                A
2014-12-31  261.0
2015-12-31  261.0
2016-12-31  261.0
2017-12-31  260.0
2018-12-31  261.0
2019-12-31  261.0
```

while the second

```
                A
2014-12-31  261.0
2015-12-31  261.0
2016-12-30  261.0
2017-12-29  260.0
2018-12-31  261.0
2019-12-31  261.0
2020-12-31    0.0
```

I was able to replicate this issue with both Python 2.7 and 3.7. The pandas version is 0.25.0.

A similar [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30353) unresolved on Pandas github.

Comment: This is an interesting behavior of `resample`. You should post the question on the pandas project. The output is o for 2020 is correct but 2020 is not expected at all in both outputs